# C++ background code analyser, like Resharper for C#?

Tags: c#, c++, resharper, code-analysis

I realize there are a number of tools that provide the other conveniences of R#, but I'm looking specifically for a tool that will tell me if I have a compile/link error before I actually try to build. Just like in C#, it should tell me if I'm missing a semicolon, referencing a missing function, etc.

In R# it has a nice red/green spot in the bottom right corner that tells you whether you have compile problems.

I had a look at CodeRush, but it was not clear to me whether it would have this functionality for c++.

Should probably mention it's for VS, though of course suggestions that work for other tools will be useful to someone reading this.

Comment: In C++ it is essentially impossible to tell if something compiles, without actually half-way compiling it (e.g. some things depend on internal memory layout). So what you are looking for is a tool that uses a compiler(library) as its backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of Visual Studio are you using?  Visual Studio 2010 and above should be able to check for syntax errors, undefined identifiers, etc.

Recent versions of [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) can also do this.  (In fact, Eclipse's code analysis checks a few potential problems like uninitialized member variables that my compiler doesn't.)  Since Eclipse is a full-blown IDE, it would not integrate with Visual Studio, but there's nothing stopping you from creating an Eclipse project containing the same files as another IDE's project and using Eclipse for editing and the other IDE for building and debugging.  (I do this to use Eclipse with Embarcadero C++Builder, because I much prefer Eclipse as an IDE to Embarcadero C++Builder.)

**Update:**  Visual C++ apparently refers to this as IntelliSense error reporting, and you can enable it under Tools, Options, Text Editor, C/C++, Advanced, IntelliSense.  [This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/raulperez/archive/2010/03/19/c-intellisense-options.aspx) has some more information.

Comment: I'm on 2010. I don't see it doing anything like that. Perhaps there's something I need to configure?

Comment: @Carlos - Check Tools, Options, Text Editor, C/C++, Advanced, IntelliSense; I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Visual Assist X. It's not as advanced as Resharper, it merely enhances the IntelliSense, but can make your C++ writing a bit easier.

Comment: I don't see it telling me about compile errors. Is there an option I need to change?

Comment: Well, no as far as I know. As PlasmaHH said, C++ has to be compiled to find about compile errors. Visual Assist X does not do that, as far as I have used it.